# How to write a feature test for something that's determined by the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, bdd

Let's say I'm working on a comments functionality that I want to add to the application I'm developing.

I can test it like so with a feature test:

```
scenario "they can comment on a book" do
  visit book_url(book)

  fill_in "Name", with: "John"
  fill_in "Comment", with: "This is a comment."
  click_button "Add Comment"

  expect(current_path).to eq(book_path(book))
  expect(page).to have_text("Your comment is successfully added")
  expect(page).to have_text(Comment.last.content)
end
```

But what if I also add a functionality, wherein the user can decide whether or not a comment needs an approval. If it doesn't need an approval, then the above test would work. But if the user changes the settings and decides that a comment needs an approval before being published, this test wouldn't work (this setting will be adjustable through an admin panel).

What would be a good way to write a test covering all these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered separate tests for each case? I.e. test the case where approval is not required separately from the case where approval is required. Maybe something like this:

```
feature "making comments when approval is not required" do
  background do
      // turn off the "approval required" setting
  end

  scenario "adding a comment" do
      // assertions
  end
end

feature "making comments when approval is required" do
  background do
      // turn on the "approval required" setting
  end

  scenario "adding a comment" do
    // assertions
  end
end
```

Note that I don't use Ruby or RSpec -- just did some quick searching --   so this might not be the most idiomatic way to do what you want.

EDIT: Or something like this

```
feature "making comments" do
  scenario "when approval is required" do
    // require approvals
    // assertions
  end

  scenario "when approval is not required" do
    // turn off approval requirement
    // assertions
  end
end
```